# swiper slider centermode problem in next js with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I'm new in programming. I created a swiper slider in my next js and typescript project.Everything is working fine. But the problem is I want to show 6 items and want to add centerSlides={true}. But If I do this, then my slider items from left and right are cutting off. If I add centerSlidesBounds={true} then initially it's work until items slides. I tried many way but it's not working. I'll be very greatfull if anyone help me about this. Thanks in advance.
Here is my codes

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

import Bose from "public/images/sponsor/bose.png";
import Amazon from "public/images/sponsor/amazon.png";
import Microsoft from "public/images/sponsor/microsoft.png";
import Netflix from "public/images/sponsor/netflix.png";
import Samsung from "public/images/sponsor/samsung.png";
import Toyota from "public/images/sponsor/toyota.png";

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Autoplay } from "swiper";
import "swiper/css";

const Sponsor = () => {
  return (
    <div className="sponsor">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <div
              className="sponsor__inner"
              data-aos="fade-up"
              data-aos-duration="400"
            >
              <div className="section__header">
                <h4 className="h4">Trusted by users and teams of all sizes</h4>
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                  <div className="wro">
                    <Swiper
                      slidesPerView={6}
                      spaceBetween={30}
                      loop={true}
                      centeredSlides={true}
                      centeredSlidesBounds={true}
                    >
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="sponsor__slider-item">
                          <Image src={Bose} priority alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="sponsor__slider-item">
                          <Image src={Amazon} priority alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="sponsor__slider-item">
                          <Image src={Microsoft} priority alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="sponsor__slider-item">
                          <Image src={Netflix} priority alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="sponsor__slider-item">
                          <Image src={Samsung} priority alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="sponsor__slider-item">
                          <Image src={Toyota} priority alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="sponsor__slider-item">
                          <Image src={Bose} priority alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="sponsor__slider-item">
                          <Image src={Amazon} priority alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="sponsor__slider-item">
                          <Image src={Microsoft} priority alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="sponsor__slider-item">
                          <Image src={Netflix} priority alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="sponsor__slider-item">
                          <Image src={Samsung} priority alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="sponsor__slider-item">
                          <Image src={Toyota} priority alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                    </Swiper>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sponsor;
```

Here is my css

```
// 04. sponsor
.sponsor {
  .sponsor__inner {
    padding: 65px;
    background-image: url("../../../public/images/sponsor/sponsor-bg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left bottom;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  .h4 {
    color: $white;
  }

  .sponsor__slider-item {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      transition: $transition;
      &:hover {
        filter: invert(82%) sepia(39%) saturate(369%) hue-rotate(111deg)
          brightness(400%) contrast(102%);
      }
    }
  }
  

  .swiper-slide-active {
    img {
      filter: invert(82%) sepia(39%) saturate(369%) hue-rotate(111deg)
        brightness(400%) contrast(102%);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe the problem with you css.
could you sent us a demo link to the problem.
and also provide this question with your css file of the swiper.

Comment: I added the css file for this. Please take a look

Comment: It's necessary to provide us with a live demo.
investigating the issue like this is so hard.